# new user registration page writes to user info to .txt, sign in verifies user exists in .txt file to allow user to log in

Tags: php, registration

I am new to php and trying to learn it.  I am practicing by doing a php code to so that when a user is at the login screen and they sign in with a username and password, when they click the sign in button, the page will check the .txt file to see if the username and password exists on the .txt file, if not it will display and error asking the user to sign up.

When the user clicks on sign up it redirects the user to the registration page.  after comleting the registration form and the user clicks submit, it will then write the user to the .txt file.  I also want it to check for the password if it is min and max.

my sign in page code I am playing around with is this:

```
// Useful variables
$datafile = "users.txt";

$file = file_get_contents($datafile);
if(!strpos($file, "search string")) {
echo "String not found!";
}

   if (array_key_exists('submit_btn', $_POST))
   {
     if(!strpos($file, "search string")) {
echo "String not found!";
}

      header('Location: 04invoice.php');
   }

   else 
       if (array_key_exists('register', $_POST))
   {

      header('Location: 03registration.php');
   }


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> <center>
    <style>
        body
        {
            background-color:aqua;
            font-family:"Times New Roman";
            font-size:20px;
        }
        h1
        {
            color:orange;
            text-align: center;
        }
        p
        {
            font-size:24px;
        }
        table
        {
            background-color:green;
            font-family:"Helvetica";
            font-size:20px;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
    </style>
    <h1>
        Welcome to the Pay'N'Go Kiosk
    </h1>
    <body>
        <form action= "<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="POST">
            <p>Username:    <br>
<input style="background-color: yellow; color:black" type='text' name='username'
                              value='<?php if(isset($_POST['username'])) 
        echo $_POST['username'] ?>'>
                              <BR>
            Password:   <br>
<input style="background-color:magenta" type='password' name='userpass'><BR>


            <input type='submit' name='submit_btn' value='Sign In'>
            <br/>
            Not a user? Sign up today! </br>
            <input type='submit' name='register' value='Sign Up'>
        </form>
    </body>
</center>
</html>
```

And my Registration page code is:

```
<center>
<form action = '<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>' method= 'POST'> 
    Username:   <br>

    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT"  name="username" value = "<?php     
    if(isset($_POST['username'])) 
        echo $_POST['username'] ?>"><br>
Password: <br>

        <INPUT TYPE="password" name = 'password'>
<?php
    if (isset($errors['password_short'])) 
        echo " <font color='red'>{$errors['password_short']}</font>";
    if (isset($errors['password_long']))  
        echo " <font color='red'>{$errors['password_long']}</font>"; 
        ?>

    <br><br>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Sign Up'>
</form>

<?php

   if (array_key_exists('submit', $_POST))
   {
   //code provided by professor Kazman
// Define constants for the shortest and longeste passwords
define('MIN_PASS_LEN', 8);    
define('MAX_PASS_LEN', 20);

// Function to check the password length
function check_pass($pword) 
{
    global $errors;
    if (strlen($pword) < MIN_PASS_LEN ) 
        $errors['password_short'] = 'Enter a longer password';    
    if (strlen($pword) > MAX_PASS_LEN ) 
        $errors['password_long'] = 'Enter a shorter password';
}


$errors = array();

// If the user pressed Submit, check the username and password
if (array_key_exists('submit', $_POST)) 
{
    check_pass($_POST['password']);   
    if (count($errors) == 0 && $_POST['username'] == $username 
        && $_POST['password'] == $password) 
    {
        die('correct!!');
    }   
}    
   }

 else               

                {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
 //the data
$data = "$username | $password\n";

//open the file and choose the mode
$fh = fopen("users.txt", "a");

fwrite($fh, $data); //close the file fclose($fh); 
//close the file

fclose($fh);
   }
?>

</center>
```

I know after  reading countless blogs and forums that .txt is not the best way to go about this but I am doing this for educational purposes.  Thanks in advance and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Rather than a .txt file, I would suggest using an .ini file as there are PHP functions to easily parse the data into readable arrays - http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php. Also make sure the txt/ini file is not publicly accessible.

Comment: A tiny hint regardingt usability: Display clear error messages. Dont have the user guess how long the password can be, provide them with the correct numbers, e.g. "Your password has to be between 8 and 20 characters". Also, enable longer passwords. See http://xkcd.com/936/ for why.

Comment: Also: my username is `"troll|"`. ;-)